# Fuse #5 keeps blowing on 2000 Dodge Stratus 2.0L

Tags: electrical, dodge, fuse

**Vehicle:**  2000 Dodge Stratus 2.0L

**Problem:**  #5 Fuse (PCM, ASD) keeps blowing when the key is turned on.

**Tried:**  Fuse does not blow when the ASD relay OR #8 fuse (IGN. FUEL STARTER) is removed. I unplugged the alternator, oxygen sensor, injectors, ignition coil pack, starter and fuel pump and the #5 fuse still blows. I suppose the problem is a short circuit somewhere.

Please advise what to do next.

Comment: I found this on you tube relating to this issue. This guy had same exact issue.
Check it out.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDdgMCQBO3A

Comment: It's apparently something related to the ASD and #8 fuse, because it doesn't blow when those are removed.

Comment: I've downvoted because you've only repeated what the OP put into their question. This would have made an okay comment, but as an answer it does nothing.

Comment: There's a radio noise suppressor that runs off that #5 fuse. I'm not sure of the location but I'd look around the valve cover for a single wire connector that bolts to the block. The two circuits shouldn't have anything to do with each other so you may want to visually inspect the wiring harness. Especially under the underhood fusebox.